# How does fundamental theorem of Galois Theory implies this statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

While reading Galois Theory from Hungerford Algebra, I have a question in proof of theorem 9.6 on page 306.

It's image:[image]

Theorem 2.5's image:

[image]

Proof: How does in line 3 of proof  $|Aut_{K} E|= [E:K] $ , implies that char K doesn't divide p?

Can you please explain.

Comment: It's part of the hypotheses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Mummy the turkey said $|Aut_KE|=|E:K|=p$ and from hypothesis $char(K)\not|p=|E:K|$